# IntelliJ reporting error running for a file non found in a module I created

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm new to programming and I've just started studying Kotlin. I'm currently dealing with Classes and Constructors. Now I'm trying to complete a "Coding challege" inside a course I'm attending. I've just finished coding everything but when I try to run everything, IntelliJ says, in a red bottom centre small window:

> Error running 'oo.Coding_Challenge_ClassesKt': Class
>   'oo.Coding_Challenge_ClassesKt' not found in module 'Kotlin_Course'

It might sound as a silly question, but in two weeks time, it's actually the first time that I have this kind of problem and can't see whether my code is correct or not.

Thanks everyone for your patience.

Comment: Post your code, your project structure and a link to the course materials (if possible). Do you have any clue what `oo.Coding_Challenge_ClassesKt` is?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just misspelled you file name, Coding_Challenge_ClassesKt instead of Coding_Challenge_Classes.Kt?

Comment: Yeah, I checked multiple times